# How to expire cache key in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

My app use Rails 4.0.0.
I have patcial model `users_posts`:

```
class UsersPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :post_id, :user_id, :example
  belongs_to :post, touch: true
```

and `posts`:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_posts
```

this is users_post view :

```
-cache users_post do
  .box.col2
    p.center
      =status_post_vk(users_post)
      =status_post_fb(users_post) 
    p = check_box_tag "posts_ids[]", users_post.id
    p = best_in_place users_post.post, :text, type: :textarea
    p = raw users_post.post_url_small.map{|url| image_tag 'http://bla.com/'+url}.join()
    p 
      = link_to 'Show', users_post
      = link_to 'Edit', edit_users_post_path(users_post)
      = link_to 'Destroy', users_post, data: { confirm: 'Text' }, :method => :delete
```

How to expire cache key whan i change the text of post (update attribute text in DB) `best_in_place users_post.post, :text, type: :textarea`?

Comment: caching form elements is not a very clever approach. honestly.

Comment: this is not a form element.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding `gem 'dalli'`.
For view:

```
-cache ["#{current_user.id}",users_post], skip_digest: true do
  .box.col2
    p.center
      =status_post_vk(users_post)
      =status_post_fb(users_post) 
    p = check_box_tag "posts_ids[]", users_post.id
    p = best_in_place users_post.post, :text, type: :textarea
    p = raw users_post.post_url_small.map{|url| image_tag 'http://bla_bla.com/'+url}.join()
    p 
      = link_to 'Show', users_post
      = link_to 'Edit', edit_users_post_path(users_post)
      = link_to 'Destroy', users_post, data: { confirm: 'Text' }, :method => :delete
```

add expire_fragment in controller like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  after_filter  :cache_clear, :only => [:create, :update, :destroy]

  def cache_clear
    expire_fragment /.*#{current_user.id}.*/
  end
```

After update, create or destroy post you cache is expire.